# JBoss to use a specific .class from the file system instead of the one supplied in the app’s .ear

Tags: java, jboss

When running an app I want JBoss to use a specific .class from the file system instead of the one supplied in the app’s .ear

e.g.

```
someDir:
| z.class(v2)

JBoss/server/all/deploy:
|--x.ear
|   `- - y.jar
|      `- - z.class(v1)
```

How to use z.class(v2) instead of z.class(v1)?

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend you read on how JBoss classloader works. I.e how it delegates to other classloaders

You can add the class to the java classpath on the filesystem but it depends on how the above works, which file gets loaded first.

A warning, do not mix different versions of the class by using the above classloaders.
The problems that you can run into can be very hard to solve.